# Broadcast Receiver within Service stops working after some time

Tags: android, service, widget, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I am currently working on a self made battery widget for my android device.
Its just and ImageView and a TextView displaying the battery level in percent.

Everything works fine actually except that somehow after some time (like 1 hour, maybe 2) the broadcastreceiver im using to listen to battery changes stops working and my UI no longer updates with the correct percentage level. What could be the cause of this?

Furthermore, I recognized that even when the receiver stops receiving and the UI is no longer updating, the service is still running.

Here my widget class:

```
public class BatteryWidgetHD extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static BatteryController bctrl;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    if(bctrl == null) bctrl = new BatteryController(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    Log.i("BatteryWidgetHD", "OnUpdate... starting service...");

    Intent batteryServiceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), BatteryMonitoringService.class);

    context.getApplicationContext().startService(batteryServiceIntent); 
}

/**
 * service that keeps the broadcastreceiver alive that listens for battery changes
 * @author philipp
 *
 */
public static class BatteryMonitoringService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {    

        if(bctrl != null) bctrl.listenToBatteryStatus();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        if(bctrl != null) bctrl.stopListeningToBatteryStatus();
    }

}
}
```

And my batterycontroller class, that has a broadcastreceiver and updates the user interface onReceive():

```
public class BatteryController {

private int status, level;
private boolean isCharging, isUSBPlugged, isACPlugged;

private Context c;

private BatteryStatusReceiver bsr;
private RemoteViews remoteViews;
private AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
private ComponentName thisWidget;

/** constructor 
 * @param appWidgetManager */
public BatteryController(Context c, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    this.c = c;
    this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.battery_widget_layout);
    thisWidget = new ComponentName(c, BatteryWidgetHD.class);

    bsr = new BatteryStatusReceiver();
}

/**
 * start listening to broadcasts concerning the battery
 */
public void listenToBatteryStatus() {

    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED); 
    c.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(bsr, ifilter);   

    getStartupBatteryLevel();
}

/**
 * stop listening to battery broadcasts
 */
public void stopListeningToBatteryStatus() {

    c.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(bsr);
}

private void updateUI() {

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvBatteryLevel, "\n" + level + "%");

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}

/**
 * this class is responsible for listening to broadcasts concerning the
 * battery status
 */
private class BatteryStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

        status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

        isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        int isPlugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

        isUSBPlugged = isPlugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
        isACPlugged = isPlugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

        // inform the UI about battery changes
        updateUI();
        Log.i("BatteryController", "BATTERY STATUS CHANGED. Level: " + level + ", Charging: " + isCharging);
       // Toast.makeText(c, "Battery status changed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

And the widget_provider.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/battery_widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="100dip"
    android:minWidth="60dip"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/battery75"
    android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0" />
```

Comment: I believe the documentation says that if your update cycle is less than 30 minutes, you have to use AlarmManager

Comment: It does indeed, but I dont rly need the update cycle I just need the onUpdate to be called once. Somewhere I read that this could be acheived by setting updatePeriodMillis to 0.

Comment: i'm facing this problem right now, did you solved this?

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry but I have only a try out for you, try making your service foreground so that the system won't kill it and handle it perfectly all the time here a code to set it foreground:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, urmainactivity.class);       
    PendingIntent pbIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, bIntent,0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder bBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("write the title")
                .setContentText("write subtitle")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(pbIntent);
    Notification barNotif = bBuilder.build();
    this.startForeground(1, barNotif);
```

and as for the receiver try making it firing the service because when u do that the receiver should stay as active as your foreground service is. and to do that...:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, urService.class);
context.startService(i);
```

don't forget to register your Service and your Receiver in the Manifest,,, hope I helped, if not well forgive me.